# shadow mapping multitexture

Tags: opengl, shadows

There is this tutorial about shadow mapping:
http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/smt/smt.html

Ok, but I did not realize how to make a scene with multitexture.

If in the third pass of shadow mapping It is need to bind the shadow mapping projected texture to perform depth comparison, HOW can I bind another textures if I need to bind the shadow mapping texture?

Must I set shadow mapping as a separate texture to be bind? Something like this:

1. Active shadow mapping texture
2. Active texture 1
3. Active texture 2

I tried that but it did not work (maybe I've done something wrong).

Comment: I am new with OpenGL, and I have the same problem as author with the same tutorial.
I don't understande everything about what you wrote, and I would like to ask you for help with this issue.
Could some one send me a simple source code how to use textures for example for floor in this tutorial.
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you have a pre-existing multi-textured scene you want to shadowmap?

If so, activating all your texture units should work (**if** you have enough, I think the OpenGL 1.4/1.5 spec only calls for a minimum of two; check GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS_ARB via glGetIntegerv()).  If you don't have enough texture units you'll have to use multi-pass rendering/blending.

Comment: Yes I have a multi-texutre scene and I want a shadowmap, but the doubt is not about the max supported (my card supports 4), but about the shadow mapping application itself.

Must I active the shadowmapping in a separate texture unit?
If so, this shadomapping tex unit, must be the first or the last?

Comment: Ah, got it.  I'm pretty sure the shadowmap texture needs a separate texture unit, and that it should come after the other texture units.

So in order, Active Texture 1, Active Texture 2, Active Shadowmap Texture

Answer (score 0):

yes, for the depth comparison pass, the shadowmap should be bound on a separate texture unit.
don't forget to also enable/disable texturing after activating the unit.